# Naming convention for years (how to write the year in words)

Tags: regex, naming-conventions, future, numeric

I wrote a program that converted a given numeric value into the corresponding english words, for example

1986 = one thousand nine hundred eighty six 
3287489358475 = three trillion two hundred eighty seven billion four hundred eighty nine million three hundred fifty eight thousand four hundred seventy five

and that easily expands as long as you know the name for the next 10^n*3 places (thousand, million, billion, etc..). This is accomplished by splitting each number into sets of three digits and then applying the same naming scheme to each set and adding a token after each set to delineate the power it represents. for example the number 12,345,665 broken into sets of three digits

- 012 = twelve
- 345 = three hundred forty five
- 665 = six hundred sixty five

then added tokens and concatenated

twelve million three hundred forty five thousand six hundred sixty five

which works ok until at least 10^183 (since there aren't really consistent names past this point) and I'm fine with that. However I was thinking I also want it to be able to covert numerical values to the way you would say it as a year, for example

- 1986 = nineteen eighty six
- 2015 = two thousand fifteen
- 2289 = twenty two eighty nine
- 21345 = ?

Up to the year 9999 the convention seems somewhat consistent you can break the number up into sets of two digits rather than three and get the names for each set of digits the same way as before. This only has a couple exceptions when dealing with pairs that start or end in zero. the exceptions being

1. if second pair begins with zero add "o" in front of ones value

   - 21 02 = twenty one o two
2. if both digits in second pair are zero add hundred

   - 11 00 = eleven hundred
3. if first pair ends with zero add "thousand" and ignore first and second rule if they applies

   - 20 05 = two thousand forty five

for numbers greater than 9999 and especially much greater than 9999 nothing really sounds like the right answer. For 236701 if you apply the same rules as in the case of numbers <= 9999 it would be twenty three sixty seven o one but the standard name two hundred thirty six thousand seven hundred one sounds just as good really. Im wondering if there is an already established naming convention for all years small and large that is accepted?

Also now that I've been thinking about this I have a side question being if humans manage to live for millions of years are they doomed to express what year they are currently living in such a terrible and cumbersome manner, or is there a better way to quickly and accurately express ones time position?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, if your software lasts for just 30 more years, it will be a miracle.

Comment: Well... your first question would be better suited for [english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/) and your second one for [woldbuilding.se](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to put one dollar in a bank account. This would allow you to hire a programmer in 7985 years that will adapt your program to the naming convention of 5 digit years that will be established by then. (This is only applicable if your program AND dollars will still exist.)

PS: I doublechecked if we are not April 1st today. :)